EAS Android apk build failed

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:


Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
Build init improvements
Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable


Task :gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava
NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:classes
Task :gradle-plugin:jar
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 408
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.


A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-constants'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 85
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.


Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with
--scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

package.json
{
"name": "abc",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"eject": "expo eject",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx --quiet",
"clean:build:android": "rm -rf android/app/build",
"prod:android": "npm run clean:build:android  && react-native 
bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js -- 
bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle -- 
assets-dest android/app/src/main/res"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
"@gluestack-style/react": "^1.0.49",
"@gluestack-ui/config": "^1.1.16",
"@gluestack-ui/themed": "^1.1.9",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.1",
"@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.5",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.15",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
"@shopify/react-native-skia": "1.2.1",
"@types/react": "~18.0.38",
"axios": "^1.6.7",
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
"expo": "^51.0.0-preview.8",
"expo-blur": "~13.0.1",
"expo-build-properties": "~0.12.0",
"expo-haptics": "13.0.1",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.1",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-localization": "~15.0.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"i18n-js": "3.8.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.0",
"react-native-autocomplete-dropdown": "^3.1.5",
"react-native-country-flag": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-fusioncharts": "^5.2.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.0",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.4",
"react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "3.9.0-rc.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.0-rc.1",
"react-native-svg": "15.2.0-rc.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
"react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
"typescript": "^5.4.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
"@types/i18n-js": "3.8.1",
"@types/react": "~18.2.45",
"eslint": "7.28.0",
"jest-expo": "~51.0.1",
"typescript": "^5.3.0"
},
"private": true,
"jest": {
"preset": "jest-expo",
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
"node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced- 
element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react- 
navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry- 
expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
]
},
"overrides": {
"expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.11.0",
"@expo/config-plugins": "~8.0.0",
"@expo/prebuild-config": "~7.0.0",
"@expo/metro-config": "~0.18.1",
"metro": "~0.80.8",
"metro-resolver": "~0.80.8",
"metro-config": "~0.80.8"
}
}

app.json
{
"expo": {
"name": "abc",
"slug": "abc",
"description": "",
"primaryColor": "#CB0C9F",
"version": "1.0.1",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "cover",
  "backgroundColor": "#1B222D"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "abc"
},
"android": {
  "package": "abc",
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#CB0C9F"
  }
},
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "compileSdkVersion": 33,
        "targetSdkVersion": 33,
        "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
      },
      "ios": {
        "deploymentTarget": "13.4"
      }
    }
  ],

  "expo-localization"
],
"extra": {
  "eas": {
    "projectId": "123"
  }
},
"owner": "abc"
 }
}


I have solved a similar error just now.
Remove the following items

node_modules
package-lock.json

Install the following items

expo-constants
expo-updates

$     npm i expo-updates && npm i expo-constants

execute the following command after everything has installed
$    npm i && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd ..


I do not have android folder as I'm on expo project and did not prebuild my project.

Then skip that step. Try only the delete and install steps.

build failed again
